# Grouping Subsidiary Values in one groups in PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014

Please consider this scenario:

We have Order table that store orders specifications. One of these specification is currency. I have several currency in that table such as *Dollar, Euro, Pound, Yen, Dirham, Rial, Rupee*. *Dollar, Euro, Pound* are main currencies. I want to group others in 1 group in my query. How I can do this using `PIVOT` command?

I want to create this such result:

```
ProductCategory        Dollar      Euro       Pound      Others
---------------------------------------------------------------
P1                     1000        2000        500        880
P2                     1200        100         200        750
P3                     1900        8000        700        640
P4                     1500        500         1000       270
P5                     2000        1700        1200       1000
```

thanks

---

**Update 1)**

My source table is like:

```
ProductCategory   Currency     Amount       
----------------------------------------
P1                Dollar       100         
P2                Euro         500    
P3                Dollar       100      
P4                Yen          200       
P1                Dollar       100       
P3                Rupee        50        
...
```

---

**Update 2)**

```
declare @tbl  table
(
    Product   nvarchar(50),
    Cur       nvarchar(50),
    Amount    int
)


insert into @tbl values
('p1', 'dollar',100),
('p2', 'euro',100),
('p3', 'pound',100),
('p1', 'a',100),
('p1', 'b',100),
('p2', 'c',100),
('p3', 'dollar',100),
('p3', 'euro',100),
('p2', 'euro',100),
('p2', 'euro',100),
('p1', 'j',100)


SELECT pv.Product
    ,ISNULL(pv.Dollar,0) AS [Dollar]
    ,ISNULL(pv.Euro,0) AS [Euro]
    ,ISNULL(pv.Pound,0) AS [Pound]
    ,ISNULL(pv.Other,0) AS [Other]
FROM (
SELECT *
    ,CASE
        WHEN [Cur] NOT IN ('dollar','euro','pound') THEN 'Other'
        ELSE [Cur]
    END AS [newCurrency] 
FROM @tbl
)as a
PIVOT (
    SUM([Amount]) 
    FOR [newCurrency] IN ([dollar],[euro],[pound],[Other])
)as pv
```

and get this result:

[image]

Comment: Show us your source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Modified your query little a bit in Update 2. I think this is what you want.

```
declare @tbl  table
(
    Product   nvarchar(50),
    Cur       nvarchar(50),
    Amount    int
)

insert into @tbl values
('p1', 'dollar',100),
('p2', 'euro',100),
('p3', 'pound',100),
('p1', 'a',100),
('p1', 'b',100),
('p2', 'c',100),
('p3', 'dollar',100),
('p3', 'euro',100),
('p2', 'euro',100),
('p2', 'euro',100),
('p1', 'j',100)

SELECT pv.Product
    ,sum(ISNULL(pv.Dollar,0)) AS [Dollar]
    ,sum(ISNULL(pv.Euro,0)) AS [Euro]
    ,sum(ISNULL(pv.Pound,0)) AS [Pound]
    ,sum(ISNULL(pv.Other,0)) AS [Other]
FROM (
SELECT *
    ,CASE
        WHEN [Cur] NOT IN ('dollar','euro','pound') THEN 'Other'
        ELSE [Cur]
    END AS [newCurrency] 
FROM @tbl
)as a
PIVOT (
    SUM([Amount]) 
    FOR [newCurrency] IN ([dollar],[euro],[pound],[Other])
)as pv
group by product
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
 SELECT pv.ProductCategory
    ,ISNULL(pv.Dollar,0) AS [Dollar]
    ,ISNULL(pv.Euro,0) AS [Euro]
    ,ISNULL(pv.Pound,0) AS [Pound]
    ,ISNULL(pv.Other,0) AS [Other]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE
            WHEN [Currency] NOT IN ('Dollar','Euro','Pound') THEN 'Other'
            ELSE [Currency]
        END AS [newCurrency] 
    FROM #tmp
)as a
PIVOT (
    MAX([Amount]) 
    FOR [newCurrency] IN ([Dollar],[Euro],[Pound],[Other])
)as pv
```

Comment: There is no `Other` column in your query. I want to sum others currency be summarize in `Other` column

Comment: Please see Update 2

Comment: Ok... I don't know about you input but if you want to get you expect result. First, you must find you result (before pivot) with sum value and not duplicate Product after that pivot you result for convert row to column.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query, You can sum the other currency based on the product.

```
select  productCategory, 
        sum(dollar), 
        sum(euro),
        sum(pound), 
        sum(others) 
from order 
group by productCategory
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I want that result using PIVOT command. It seems that my table hasn't one column for every currency!!!